# Performance issues in IE11 using ExtJS 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am facing performance issues with Tabs Panel for *IE9* (and above) if I even open just 2-3 tabs with HTML document of size varying from 1MB to 20MB. Then on switching between tabs it’s taking around 3-4 seconds (when page has only tab panel) and around 5-6 seconds (when page has a lot of other extjs components) on IE-11. The response is almost 1-2 secs on *IE8* which is very surprising.

I also tried with different *hideMode* options (Display, offsets, visibility, asclass) but with not much benefit although `hideMode='asclass'` is comparatively fast than other options.

I also created a sample page to confirm if it is really document size issue or *extjs* component issue. Created simple tabs (with **divs**) without any JS library and just changed their *css z-index* (instead of css display or css visibility) and they were switching instantly (on all IE versions). Trying the same solution on a separate page for *ExtJS* doesn't help on *IE11* (somewhat faster on IE8). So it seems to be *ExtJS* specific issue.

Has anyone else ever faced this issue? Any comments or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the profiler for IE to see whether any scripts related to ExtJS 4.2.1 take a long time to load.  If you discover such a script, you can then proceed to making a bug report for this library.

Here's some detailed information of how to do JavaScript profiling in IE.

[Profiling JavaScript performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: These scripts run fine on CHrome,firefox, its basically a problem on IE browsers only. Nothing wrong with the script files.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox use different interpreters, meaning IE does execute scripts differently.

Comment: OK, but as i stated in my question, its not to do with IE since it takes way less time on IE8 surprisingly (read my question). The issue lies in ExtJS.

Comment: @DanielSarosi it's right about the profiler, IE is really slow compared to other browsers, some of the differences with IE 8 and other IE may be related to different internal drawing routines, however in my experience I found that most of the performance issues are caused by my code, keep attention to several layout modification, use Ext.suspendLayouts() and Ext.resumeLayouts() methods to keep UI from updating when you are making changes, also each() routines are really bad for performance, specially on IE. use document.getElementsByTagName('*').length to keep track of the DOM elements count.